# Download manager for chrome in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, google-chrome, downloads, download-manager

How can I integrate kget into google chrome? Alternatively what other good download managers are there for chrome that will work in Kubuntu?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Chrome is developed by Google and it is unlikely they will integrate kget directly into it.

If you look through the Chrome Web store and search for 'download manager' you will get quite a few extensions available - I cannot vouch for how well any of them work as I use the built in Chrome download manager.

Answer (score 2):

Use FatRat it have browser integration ;) http://fatrat.dolezel.info/browser-integration